# Altium 17: Multichannel Design "contains floating input pins"

Tags: altium, floating

I get

> Net SCL/SCK contains floating input pins (Pin U1.1-4,Pin U1.2-4)

as the only error after compiling the project but I don't know why.
The clock signal as well as V+ is shared among the different channels.
V+ doesn't rais an error probably because it's connected to the sheet's power port via an inductor.

What's wrong with the design?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the used harnesses in the design required a netlabel each. After that, there were no more compilation errors.